# media player sound stop() doesn't work

Tags: android

I have these two options in the menu of an activity

option one starts a music track and option two should stop it, but it isn't.

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     MediaPlayer mpSoundTrack = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.app_score);

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.icon:     Toast.makeText(this, "Music On!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mpSoundTrack.start();
                            break;
        case R.id.icontext: Toast.makeText(this, "Music Off!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mpSoundTrack.stop(); 
                            break;
    }
    return true;
     }
```

Comment: Is the player playing something at the time when you press the stop button?

Comment: yes, it was playing the music file that is started when the user clicks the first option of the switch. Buddy below has shown me how to fix it. thanks for your interest though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you create a new mediaPlayer, so you stop a new one, not the old one. You should keep a reference to it:

```
private MediaPlayer mpSoundTrack = null;

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.icon:     
            Toast.makeText(this, "Music On!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mpSoundTrack = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.app_score);
            mpSoundTrack.start();
            break;
        case R.id.icontext: 
            Toast.makeText(this, "Music Off!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(mpSoundTrack != null)
                mpSoundTrack.stop(); 
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Much obliged. I don't know whether to bother trying to keep the sound playing while changing activity or not. Assignment has to be uploaded in 2 hours :).   But sincerely, you have my thanks

Comment: You can still stop it in `onPause()` this way, in your way you lose the reference to the media player.